# How do I skip wrapper JSON object in Jackson when deserializing Scala case class?

Tags: json, scala, jackson

I have data coming out of an external system on the following kind of format:

```
{
  "type": "text",
  "data": {
    "text": "Here's some text"
  }
}
```

There are many values for `type` with different fields in `data`, all with corresponding case classes into which they should be deserialized as part of a top level stucture, eg:

```
case class TopLevel(parts: Part)
sealed trait Part
case class Text(text: String) extends Part
case class Image(url: String, ...) extends Part
...
```

How can I do this in a nice way without creating a wrapper around `Part`?

Comment: Can you add annotations on `Part`?

Comment: Yeah, the internal representation of the model is mine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a custom serializer for your types. Something like this:

```
import org.json4s.{CustomSerializer, DefaultFormats, Extraction, JObject, JString}
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods.parse
import org.json4s.jackson.Serialization

class PartSerializer extends CustomSerializer[Part](format => ( {
  case JObject(("type", JString(typeString)) :: ("data", obj) :: Nil) =>
    implicit val f = format

    typeString match {
      case "text" =>
        Extraction.extract[Text](obj)
      case "image" =>
        Extraction.extract[Image](obj)
    }
}, {
  case text: Text =>
    implicit val f = format

    JObject(List(
      ("type", JString("text")),
      ("data", JObject(List(
        ("text", JString(text.text))))
      ),
    ))
  case img: Image =>
    implicit val f = format

    JObject(List(
      ("type", JString("image")),
      ("data", JObject(List(
        ("url", JString(img.url))))
      ),
    ))
}
))
```

You can then use it like this:

```
implicit val formats = DefaultFormats + new PartSerializer()

// Parse JSON
val part = Extraction.extract[Part](parse(json))
// Generate JSON
val json = Serialization.write(part)
```

This also works if the `Part` data is embedded in an outer object.

Comment: Thanks! How would I use this with an `ObjectMapper`?

Comment: Looking [here](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-custom-serialization) it seems that you call `mapper.addSerializer(Part.class, new PartSerializer())`, but I don't use the object mapper so this may be wrong.

Comment: Oh, wait. I must have been really tired. What I meant was deserialization, not serialization :/

Comment: A `CustomSerializer` does both serialization and deserialization, as you can see in my example. So maybe `addSerializer` will work anyway? As I said, I don't use the object mapper so I can't easily test this.